# Should the WEB-INF/lib directory be versioned by a version control system?

Tags: version-control, jakarta-ee

Should the `WEB-INF/lib` directory and it's contents be versioned by a VCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can easily **rebuild** its content, I would argue against versioning it.

Considering one of the main goals of a VCS (manage the history and get the delta between one version and the other), the history and delta of binaries is often not well managed in a VCS.

those binaries are best referenced through an **artifact repository** (like Nexus), where a **building script** (like Maven) can access and copy them where they are needed (like a `WEB-INF/lib` directory for instance).

Comment: I already use maven. But there is a bug or sth. leading to that eclipse wtp does not deliver the dependencies to tomcat when you start it out of eclipse. I have to research this again, maybe its fixed now. But there may be other reasons to just put your libs there, the old way. Also I don't think, that the libs will be changed themselves, but may be changed to another version.

Comment: @Pascal: thank you, Sir. I've got 8 years of binary history in a VCS (ClearCase), so it is a very sensible topic for me ;) I now manage a Nexus pro repo precisely for that, as well well as the rest (Hudson, FishEye/Crucible, Sonar), and other VCS (SVN, Git).

Comment: Wow, that ClearCase repo must be a huge beast. The other parts of  the mentioned infrastructure look sexier :D