# CC2SVN - Jar migration problem

Tags: svn, migration, clearcase

I migrate a Clearcase project to a SVN project.

My Clearcase project is composed of :

```
Br_Int => Br_Dev => Br_2 and Br_1
```

I have created a view on `Br_int` and I have processed the migration with this view.

In my SVN project, branches are migrated :

```
Branches => Br_int and Br_Dev and Br_1 and Br_2
```

But in my ClearCase project I have `Jar` files in `Br_Dev` and I don't find these `Jar` files in no SVN branches.

I don't understand the reasons. Can you help me on this explication ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Are those files (jar) private? (meaning they are only visible in your view referencing the UCM stream `Br_Dev`)?

Or does your import mechanism configured to ignore binaries? (including jars).

It is not a good practice to version binaries (as I mention in "[Should the WEB-INF/lib directory be versioned by a version control system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865383/should-the-web-inf-lib-directory-be-versioned-by-a-version-control-system/3865410#3865410)"), so it is possible that those files are:

- not "add to source control" in ClearCase
- or have an "element type" which mark them as "to be ignore" by the import mechanism you have used

---

Note: for this kind of import, I usually only import in SVN the UCM baselines set in the Streams (i.e. not the *full* history with the intermediate file versions which are not labeled).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

There aren't private files. Such projects want to migrate these binaries even if it is no a good practice.

So I have done my migration from Int and there aren't all versions in this ClearCase stream, thereby such binaries aren't migrated.